# cakephp does not send an activation

Tags: cakephp-1.3

Can anyone Help me ? my cakephp does not send an activation link after registration.
When a user registers, the user does not receive an activation link. Can you help me ? how do i fix these errors?
I've tried everything possible. still bug, bug.

```
          'Email' => array(
                'delivery' => 'smtp',
                'sendAs'   => 'both',
                'host'     => 'w0232ed3.02393.de',
                'port'     => 587,
                'timeout'  => 60,
                'username' => 'support@swoopo.de',
                'password' => '373673763'
            ),
    
            'Cache' => array(
                //'disable' => true,
                'check' => false,
                'time' => '' // relative time such as +1 day, +2 months, +3 minutes
            ),
    
            'debug' => 0
        );
```

Comment: Is it even trying to send such an email? How do you know for sure? If it tries, does it fail to send (which should result in an error message somewhere) or does it send but not get received?

Comment: when registering he gives an error message.

Comment: That's useful information. What does the error message say? We're not mind readers here. :-)

Comment: Error Message .: Email sending failed. Please try again or contact the administrator.

Comment: That sounds like a user-side error. I mean the error your code is encountering. Maybe in your Cake logs? Or maybe being caught by your code and not recorded anywhere. Without any code to look at, again, it's very hard to say.